# Using custom module import error on python3 version

Tags: python

I've created a custom module called config which have the following structure:

```
config/
    __init__.py
    config.py
    util.py
```

---

Each file is defined like:

config.py

```
CONTROL_VAR = "A"
```

util.py

```
from config import CONTROL_VAR

if CONTROL_VAR == "A":
    VAR_ONE = "A1"
else:
    VAR_ONE = "B1"
```

---

I've setup my workspace like the following:

```
workspace_folder
    config/
    my_script.py
```

In order tu run my script I invoke it directly by running:

```
python my_script.py
```

my_script.py has the following code:

```py
from config.config import CONTROL_VAR
from config.util import VAR_ONE

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (CONTROL_VAR)
    print (VAR_ONE)
```

I am able to run the code with python 2.7 but not with 3.8, at first I thought i was having a circular dependency issue but now it seems like I have something wrong with my import syntax.

Can I make this work for both python2 and python3?

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: File "my_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from config.util import VAR_ONE

File ".../config/util.py" , line 1, in <module>

    from config import CONTROL_VAR

ImportError: cannot import name 'CONTROL_VAR' from 'config' (.../config/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform `from config import CONTROL_VAR` inside `config/util.py` that module (`util.py`) doesn't know that it's located inside the `config` package and hence the resolution will start from `my_script.py`'s directory. That means even the import happens inside a module which is located *inside* `config`, it attempts to resolve that import from the perspective *outside* of `config`.

In order to change that behavior, you can prefix `config` with a `.` which tells Python that the `config.py` module is expected to be in the same directory as the `util.py` module:

```py
from .config import CONTROL_VAR
```

The `from .foo import bar` and `from ..foo import bar` syntax instructs Python so resolve imports *relative* to the *importing* module. A plain `from foo import bar` on the other hand resolves `foo` as a "global" module (i.e. not relative to anything).

Comment: Thx!! this solved my issue. What I don't really get is why it worked on python2

Comment: @Ryag1 In Python 2, package-relative imports had a higher precedence than absolute imports. I.e. inside `util.py` there is `from config import CONTROL_VAR` and this will *first* check for a module `config.py` inside the same package as `util.py` (it takes precedence over the one already cached in `sys.modules`). This is described in the second to last paragraph [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) or in [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports).

Comment: As described in the docs for [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) this behavior can be disabled by doing `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the first line of a module (it then behaves similar to Python 3, giving that error; note that this must be done in the same module where the import happens, i.e. `util.py`).